# BusinessHours and scheduled dates

Tags: apex, date, datetime, businesshours

I am trying to create a payment schedule off of a input field `DATE`. If the date falls on a Weekend or on a Holiday then I want to move the payment date to the next open business day.

I was using the `BusinessHours` class to help me solve this but the business hours for the company takes into consideration the business hours. ha I know. I do not want to include the business hours, just the days. I also don't want to have to change the core business hours just to make this logic work.

For example: a user schedules a payment date of Monday at 5am. The business hours don't start until 7am. The logic will keep searching for the next available business day.

Is there a better class that only takes into consideration the business DAYS or should I work around the hours by pulling the DateTime, stripping the time (even though when I do this it still leaves a 00:00:00 time), and then pushing to the `nextStartDate()`?

Thoughts?

Here is some code I started:

```
public Datetime scheduler(String varFrequency, Datetime schedDateTime){
        BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];

        if (BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.Id, schedDateTime)){ //this will come up as FALSE if the time isn't between 7am - 6pm M-F
            schedDateTime = schedDateTime.addDays(1);
        } 
        else {
            schedDateTime = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id, schedDateTime);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the method as below.

If `schedDateTime` is within business hour then no need to do alteration, otherwise, it will return the nearest next datetime.

Here `nextStartDate` will take two parameters BusinessHourId and input Datetime, as opposed to only BusinessHourId which you have used.

```
public Datetime scheduler(String varFrequency, Datetime schedDateTime)
{

    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];

    if (!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.Id, schedDateTime))
    { 
        return BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id,schedDateTime);
    }
    return schedDateTime;
}

public Date returnSchedulerDate(String varFrequency, Datetime schedDateTime)
{
    DateTime dt = scheduler(varFrequency,schedDateTime);
    return Date.newinstance(dT.year(), dT.month(), dT.day());
}
```

Comment: thank you, that was a typo on my part. You are right, I missed the second parameter. My issue is that I don't want to take the time into consideration. The situation where `schedDateTime` is on the right day but not on the right time is going to happen often. Is there a way around this?

Comment: this should the right time too. Just for sake of testing, make Business hour's timezone and user's timezone same. You will get the correct time

Comment: Santanu, even if I change the timezones to be the same, I do not want to take into account the hours. If a user submits a time outside of the core business hours, I still want to use that DATE. Does that make sense?

Comment: so what it is returning when you submit outside of business hours?

Comment: If you want the date from datetime which the method is returning then create a separate method the way I have updated my answer